# Append Dictionary in List - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list and dictionaries in it.

Where (1,2,3) belongs to Z,
(4,5,6) belongs to X,
(7,8,9) belongs to V.

But it overwrites it because it constantly adds to the list in the dict.
When I use "=", I can only get the last data.

I want the output to be like this.

```
{'Property1': 'Z', 'Property2': [(1, 2, 3)]}
{'Property1': 'X', 'Property2': [(4, 5, 6)]}
{'Property1': 'V', 'Property2': [(7, 8, 9)]}
```

```
A1 = ["Z","X","V"]
A2 = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]

list = []
Dict = {"Property1": "",
        "Property2": [""],
        }


for a in A1:
    Dict["Property1"] = a
    
    for b in A2:
        Dict["Property2"].append(A2)
    
    list.append(Dict)

    print("-------\n")
    print(Dict)
```

Now Output:

```
 {'Property1': 'Z', 'Property2': ['', [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]]}
-------

{'Property1': 'X', 'Property2': ['', [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]]}
-------

{'Property1': 'V', 'Property2': ['', [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)], [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: the loop that you are using is not correct you need to use one element at a time but for each element of A1 you are iterating over A2 every time.

Comment: Your inner for loop `for b in A2:`, is causing all the elements in A2 to be added in the dictionary for each element in A1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use `zip()` method

```
A1 = ["Z","X","V"]
A2 = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
List=[{"Property1": i,
        "Property2": [j],
        } for i,j in zip(A1,A2)]
print(List)
```

Output

```
[{'Property1': 'Z', 'Property2': [(1, 2, 3)]}, {'Property1': 'X', 'Property2': [(4, 5, 6)]}, {'Property1': 'V', 'Property2': [(7, 8, 9)]}]
```

For your code, you are appending all items in `A2` with every iteration, but not clearing them

Instead, change the loop to this

```
for b,a in enumerate (A1):
    Dict["Property1"] = a

    Dict["Property2"]=[A2[b]]
    list1.append(Dict)
    print("-------\n")
    print(Dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both the lists are of same length, you can iterate over them using `len()` and update your Dict.

*Don't use `list` as variable names. It's a reserved word in Python.*

```
A1 = ["Z","X","V"]
A2 = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]

lst = []
Dict = {}

n = len(A1)
for i in range(n):
    Dict["Property1"] = A1[i]
    Dict["Property2"] = [A2[i]]
    lst.append(dict(Dict))

for l in lst:
    print(l)
```

```
{'Property1': 'Z', 'Property2': [(1, 2, 3)]}
{'Property1': 'X', 'Property2': [(4, 5, 6)]}
{'Property1': 'V', 'Property2': [(7, 8, 9)]}
```